# Working on a count sorted array

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I can work on an array sorted this way:

```
$countValues = array_count_values($someArray);
arsort($someArray);
```

I want to find the first value of the sorted array that abide some criterias. Say for example,  you have an array with bananas, apples and tea. I want to find the most representative member of the array that isn't an apple. So if we have the array:

[apple, banana, apple, banana, tea]

after being sorted it would turn out to be this:

( [apple] => 2 [banana] => 2 [tea] => 1 )

So how do I find the most represented value that isn't an apple. Hope you can follow.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I tried foreach loops, but I couldn't figure out how to get the key out of it and not only the value itself.

I also tried to delete the values, but couldn't find a proper way to delete the values from the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$countValues = array_count_values($someArray);
unset($countValues['apple']); // Remove apple from array.
arsort($countValues);
$most_popular = array_values($countValues)[0]; // Get first item from array (pop).
```

Comment: Right, for some reason I couldn't get unset to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe because you ran `arsort()` on the wrong array in your question.